# Play not recognising AuthenticatorResult as Result

Tags: playframework-2.6, silhouette

In my code, I am returning the `AuthenticatorResult` created by the `embed` method of `CookieAuthenticatorService`. But I am getting compilation error

`Error:(270, 27) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.services.AuthenticatorResult]
 required: play.api.mvc.Result
                          result`

My code is

```
val result:Future[AuthenticatorResult] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(cookie, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user"))))
result
```

the code works if I return `Ok` instead of `result`

This works

```
val result:Future[AuthenticatorResult] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(cookie, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user"))))
//result
Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("registration not complete")))
```

I have defined my Action as 
`def signInUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {..}`

What am I doing wrong?

`AuthenticatorResult` is define here - http://api.play.silhouette.rocks/5.0.0/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/api/services/AuthenticatorResult.html

`CookieAuthenticatorService` is define here - http://api.play.silhouette.rocks/5.0.0/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/authenticators/CookieAuthenticatorService.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, my bad. The issue is not with `AuthenticatorResult` but `Future{AuthenticatorResult}`. I should have used `flatMap` instead of `map` in my code just before returning `result`. This is the working piece of code.

```
val cookieAuthenticatorFuture: Future[CookieAuthenticator] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.create(loginInfo) //create authenticator

                      cookieAuthenticatorFuture.flatMap(cookieAuthenticator => {
                        val cookieFuture: Future[Cookie] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.init(cookieAuthenticator) //init authenticator
                        cookieFuture.flatMap(cookie => { //this was earlier map. Changed it to flatMap and it worked.
                          val result:Future[AuthenticatorResult] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(cookie, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user"))))
                          result

                        })
```